# How to put an icon into a button (MahApps)

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I want to put a icon from the MahApps library into a normal button. I tried it this way:

```
<Button Height="20" Width="25" Background="Transparent" Foreground="White" Content="{StaticResource appbar_close}"/>
```

Which ended like this:

[image]

So how can I integrate this icon into this button in a suitable position?

Comment: Can you show the code of the **appbar_close**? With `Content="{StaticResource appbar_close}"` we cannot know what are you using.

Comment: This code is built in from MahApps: http://mahapps.com/guides/icons-and-resources.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have 2 options.

First you can use the Icon rersources (sample with MetroCircleButtonStyle)

```
<Button Width="50"
        Height="50"
        Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}">
    <Rectangle Width="20"
                Height="20"
                Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}">
        <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{DynamicResource appbar_close}" />
        </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
    </Rectangle>
</Button>
```

and second the new Icon packs

```
<Button Width="50"
        Height="50"
        Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}">
    <Controls:PackIconModern Width="20" Height="20" Kind="Close" />
</Button>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

As you can see in the [github example](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/tree/1.2.3/samples/MetroDemo/ExampleViews/ButtonsExample.xaml), they put a **Rectangle** inside the **Button** and then use the **OpacityMask** property.

```
<ToggleButton Width="50"
          Height="50"
          IsEnabled="False"
          Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleToggleButtonStyle}">
<Rectangle Width="20"
           Height="20"
           Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ToggleButton}}}">
    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill"
                     Visual="{DynamicResource appbar_city}" />
    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
</Rectangle>
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244461/mahapps-metro-icon-not-showing)

Comment: Using a `VisualBrush` is expensive, you can use a `Drawing` directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following ... just as suggested by @ganchito55

```
<Button Width="25" Height="20">
  <Button.Content>
    <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20">
          <Rectangle.Fill>
            <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource appbar_close}" Stretch="None" />
          </Rectangle.Fill>
     </Rectangle>
 </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my application I used this code before to create lots of button's with icons:

```
 <Button Command="{Binding EditDetailCommand}" ToolTip="Edit" Style="{DynamicResource buttonstyle}">
                        <metro:PackIconModern Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Kind="Edit" />
                    </Button>
```

It seems not to work with the latest MahApps anymore?

I really liked the simple syntax as I think it's more than enough to fill up my xaml files.

Comment: I don't really see a huge difference between the new and the old syntax

Comment: Well, Rectangle & VisualBrush are included in the style?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to have the Icon only as a clickable control and this is how it works for me with latest Mahapps version:

```
<Button Width="16"
        Height="16"
        Padding="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Click="HelpButton_Click"
        Style="{x:Null}"
        Background="Transparent"
        BorderThickness="0"
        >
    <Button.Content>
        <Icons:PackIconMaterial Kind="Help"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Hope this helps someone